# Use for trackless / bare stripboard?

Tags: soldering, stripboard

I've seen a few stripboards laying around that have no copper tracks. After looking online I can see that you can indeed buy these but I can't seem to find why or how to use them.

How can you use it if there's no tracks to solder too?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's often called perfboard (perforated board).

You poke the leads of through-hole components through the holes, bend them to provide mechanical security then solder those leads to each other or to wires.

[image]
<sup>*Example from [here](http://www.diyguitarist.com/TestEquipment/FunctionGenerator.htm)*</sup>

Embroidery for engineers.

Comment: Aha. So really all the components are hanging from the board being held in due to all the bent leads being soldered to each other

Comment: The truth is that sometimes the factory have a surplus of holes, so they make a load of these boards to use up the holes. Other days they have too much copper but run out of holes, and that's where the plain copper-clad with no holes/strips comes from.