# Holed none-copper clad green epoxy glass soldering problem vectorbord model

Tags: soldering

---

TO MODERATOR

Tis question is different from the post from [Use for trackless / bare stripboard?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/98224/use-for-trackless-bare-stripboard)  DO NOT MARK AS DUPLICATE AS HAVE MANY PEOPLE LINK TO THIS PAGE TO ASSIST ME WITH IDEAS.  Placing a fake link  is completely impolite , rude an uncalled.
................................................................
[image]I am very new at electronic soldering.  I got a different type of prototyping board which can not determine how to properly solder components.

It is a Vectorbord green epoxy board with holes but no copper clad.  I tried to solder with flux and solder from Radio Shack but the solder does not bond to the board.  I have look the specification but I am to able to determine if these type of board are for etching or just need a specific solder and flux.  Please help.

[image]

Comment: Please supply a photo of this board. Also, where did you buy it, and what advice did the supplier give to you about how to use it? "I tried to solder with flux and solder from Radio Shack but the solder does not bond to the board." - Can you solder to other boards?

Comment: If there is no copper, you have a problem. It's not possible to solder to green epoxy. However, you might think about using tinned bus wire, and/or the leads of the components and solder to that. It would be better, though, to get a different proto board with copper. There are many different types.

Comment: Yes I am able to solder easily to copper clad boards. But not to this green type.

Comment: "Yes I am able to solder easily to copper clad boards. But not to this green type." OK, so we don't suspect your equipment or soldering technique. If there is absolutely *no* copper on the board at all, then it is not designed for soldering *to* the board, and also not for etching (as you suggested). I wonder if there is small plated rings around each hole, or not. When you provide a photo of the board, then readers will have a chance to suggest how it could/should be used. As I asked before, the supplier of the board may have suggestions about how to use it - after all, they sold it!

Comment: You said: "I have look the specification" - Please provide that specification (of the board, I assume) to us e.g. a website link etc. "I am to able to determine if these type of board are for etching or just need a specific solder and flux." - Just to be clear, I think you meant "I am **not** able to determine [...]". If my guess is correct, then please edit your question to clarify that. Again, when you provide that "specification" you mentioned, readers will be able to help interpret it.

Comment: If there is no copper on the board, just an array of holes on 0.1" centers, you would just use the board as a holder for components - push component leads through the holes, and bend the leads to hold the components in the board, then solder wires between component leads as needed to complete your circuit. (and next time you buy a board, read the specs so you know what you're getting.)

Comment: I finally added the pictures. This is a green board. It reads Epoxy glass. but I am not sure this board soldering technique.

Comment: There is a duplicate of this question somewhere on EE.SE. If you use the search tool you'll probably find it.

Comment: I don't seea duplicate. It is just my original question that was edited to add the images requested by commenters.

Comment: Found it: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/98224/use-for-trackless-bare-stripboard

Comment: Please remove the duplicate annotation. You are interfering with my share on other social media and confusion my cicle of participants.

Comment: There are better boards to use, ones with copper.  Check Amazon.